# IdThreadMgr.hppというのはC++ Builderのコンポーネントですか？

Tags: c++

Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.3のコミュニティー版をインストールして、Borland C++ Builder6で作成された時のプロジェクトを開いてビルドを行ってみました。

```
[bcc32c 致命的エラー] Main.h(25): 'IdThreadMgr.hpp' file not found
```

このようなエラーが出てきました。
PCのCドライブで”IdThreadMgr.hpp”ファイルを探してみたのですが、無いようです。
TCP/IPサーバのプロジェクトなのですが、googleで検索してみたところ、どうもIndyというコンポーネントの一部のようです。

このエラーの回避方法など、ご教示頂きますよう、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: この辺の記事を参考にしたら、入手できるかもしれませんね。[Indy – Internet Direct](https://www.indyproject.org/), [Indy 10 Installation Instructions](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx), [ANSI 版 Delphi (5～2007) に最新版の Indy10 をインストールする](https://ht-deko.com/tech034.html), [Indy コンポーネントのインストール - Mr.XRAY](http://mrxray.on.coocan.jp/Delphi/Others/D6_IndyInstall.htm)

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。やはりTCP/IP関係のIndyのコンポーネントのようですね。今、このプロジェクトのソースコードにIdThreadMgrがある記述を検索してみると、”TIdThreadMgrDefault *TIdThreadMgrDefault”などの記述が見つかりました。これはBorland Cpp Builder6のときには存在したコンポーネントで最新のCpp Builderでは削除されているという意味でしょうか？

Comment: 事情は分かりません。そもそもキーワード検索の連想・連鎖を続けて見つけただけですので。